# android sqlite create index with where clause fails

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

In theory simple sql statement:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX i1 ON MyTable (col1, col2) WHERE col3 IS NULL;
```

However when trying to execute the statement, I get:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "WHERE": syntax error: , while compiling: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX
```

Why???? Is there any workaround?

Comment: is your tablename really `Table`? If yes, here's your error. You need double quotes around your tablename

Comment: Sorry I simply wanted to simplify the example as I have quite long tables names and index names. So that's not the case. I'm very sorry for this. But still don't know why where is not accepted. I've corrected this.

Comment: These column name are same as in you db?

Answer (score 7):

I haven't used indexes in android but it appears in the [sqlite changelog](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html) that partial indexes became available in SQLite 3.8.0.

I think that most android devices (4.3 and prior for certain), use earlier versions of SQLite. In a terminal emulator or adb shell, use `sqlite3 --version` to see the version of SQLite your device is running. If it is prior to 3.8.0, then it doesn't support partial indexes and you will have to dismiss the WHERE clause.

Actually, you should dismiss the WHERE clause anyway, since many users will not have the appropriate sqlite version to use your app when you publish it. It is not necessary anyway.

Comment: Yeah, that's the answer. Version!!! However how to have unique index on 3 columns where null values in one column are accepted? Any workaround? (and I'm not able to modify data, thus in database I have to keep null in column). And I would treat null as some kind of zero value (ex. two records A, B, null are not allowed). Is that feasible?

Comment: You can do that, no need to workaround. `For the purposes of unique indices, all NULL values are considered to different from all other NULL values and are thus unique`. See here http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html

Comment: You mean I can't do that? If I add "A, B, null" and again "A, B, null", the second row will be accepted. However I want that the second record would be rejected.

Comment: @user2707175 Sorry, I misunderstood. I don't see how you can do that without changing the current data (e.g. replace nulls with zeros), or the column declaration (e.g. `alter table` and to set column `default value` and/or `not null`)

Comment: @fobis, thank a lot for help. Unfortunately Android quite often suprises me in the negative way... :(